# upload small thumbnail images from iPhone app to Google App Engine

Tags: iphone, image, google-app-engine, thumbnails

in my iPhone app, it will allow user to abtain a photo from Camera or photo gallery, the app will resize the picture into couple small thumbnail images (64x64 eg) and then send request(s) to the web service (runs on Google App Engine) to get the thumbnail images uploaded/stored on Google App Engine. Later on, the images would be send as response (in JSON format) to other clients - think about the user profile images on Facebook iPhone app feed view.

Question is - is it achieveable? has anyone tried to do the same thing? will it better to have the images stored on Amazon S3 instead?

Comment: As long as your web service handles the POST request without issues, yes this is possible, no matter what back-end you use.

Answer (score 2):

It's absolutely achievable, as long as you know how to properly authenticate the device and send the images to the Google service.

Answer (score 0):

As stated earlier - absolutely doable. Here's a link to a quick tutorial in Python (there is also similar stuff for Java): http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/images/usingimages.html

The cool part is that static image this small can be stored in the datastore directly (as BlobProperty). Larger files have to go into the blobstore and retrieved separately.

Comment: By the way, you can also manipulate images in GAE, so you don't have to resize them in the app...

Comment: does the static image stored in the datastore comes with an URL as well?